# ExpressMapper, .NET Core, and Dependency Injection

Tags: .net-core, express-mapper

I'm evaluating different object-to-object mappers for a .NET Core web API. One of the requirements I have is to use the  built-in Dependency Injection container of .NET Core.  I have tested Automapper, which is successful, but I'm interested in trying ExpressMapper. http://www.expressmapper.org/ The examples to configure are very sparse.

I see from Github page it appears to be .netcore ready.
https://github.com/fluentsprings/ExpressMapper

How can I configure ExpressMapper in startup.cs so that I can DI into a controller, similar to Automapper?

If someone had a quick startup.cs example for  ExpressMapper  and .NET Core that would be great. 
(And as an aside, if someone was using another competitive mapper tool with .NET Core that they would recommend, that would also be helpful).

With Automapper I can add a MappingProfile class  then do  something like

Startup.cs

```
 private MapperConfiguration _mapperConfiguration { get; set; }
_mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
        });
```

ConfigureServices

```
 services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(sp => _mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper());
```

Controller

```
 public ValuesController(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The same with Expressmapper you can use `IMappingServiceProvider` interface and `MappingServiceProvider` implementation that Mapper static class uses. Please take a look at the following example and here is the [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bdNz0L) to see it in real:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var container = new Container();

        container.Register<IMappingServiceProvider, MappingServiceProvider>();

        var mapper = container.GetInstance<IMappingServiceProvider>();

        var result = mapper.Map<Test, TestResponse>(new Test{Name = "Just a test"});

        Console.WriteLine("result is {0} type", result as TestResponse);
        Console.WriteLine("result.Name = {0}", result.Name);
    }

    public class Test{
        public string Name {get;set;}
    }

    public class TestResponse{
        public string Name {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: [@George Anisimov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1008649/george-anisimov) I tried to add expressmapper 1.9 to .NET core project and it keeps giving me warning that it is 4.6 based and cannot be used in .NET core. how can I use Expressmapper in .nET core project. can you please please guide?